# Upgrading the R version to 3.6 broke the Shiny server libraries access

Tags: r, shiny

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, and have a shiny server 1.5.12.

The R version was 3.4, and for compatibility reason I upgraded to 3.6.3.

Many packages complained then that they could not be loaded because of a version incompatibility. I went through each of them to re-installe them.

But when running my shiny app I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Here is the libPaths

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

I have removed and re-installed this package as root or shiny user, without success, and forced the libPath in an Rprofile within the app, without any success as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago. For me it helped me to first update all packages with:

```
update.packages(ask=FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)
```

If this does not help, you may consider to uninstall the old version, remove the site libraries and install everything from scratch. Before that, retrieve the vector of installed packages with

```
installed.packages()[,1]
```

and save the  result to a file.

In my case, method 1 `update.packages` and the addition a few system libraries helped.